# Is there a way to get the referrer of the AMP HTML from within a iframe inside it?

Tags: iframe, amp-html, google-amp

We have integrated AMP analytics script with amp-iframe tag. We can't able to use the amp-analytics tag for various reasons. We need an AMP HTML's referrer information in the iframe for identifying the source of traffic to the AMP page. The amp-iframe src will point to our domain/subdomain. When the AMP page loaded from Google CDN it will be in the different domain. Is there any way to get the referrer of the AMP HTML within amp-iframe HTML?

Please find the example AMP HTML structure

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title of the AMP HTML</title>
        <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example1.com/example-content" />
        <script custom-element="amp-iframe" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-iframe-0.1.js" async></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js" async></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <amp-iframe class="amp-analytics" width="1" height="1" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" frameborder="0" layout="fixed" src="https://iframe.example.com/amp-analytics?query1=value1&query2=value2">
            <amp-img src="https://www.example.com/inc/amp/placeholder.png" height="1" width="1" layout="fill" placeholder></amp-img>
        </amp-iframe>
        <div>Content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get the referrer information of the AMP HTML inside the iframe `https://iframe.example.com/amp-analytics`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please show what you have attempted

Comment: @JayGray I have added the sample AMP HTML code. Could you please check?